# No qualifying bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Stuying Springboot, I got myself into an infinite wormhole of errors. Here is the last one:
    No qualifying bean of type 'ca.company.hello.A' available

However, what puzzles me is that I do define the bean:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }

    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@Profile("client_app_profile_name")

@SpringBootApplication

public class Helloer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Helloer.class, args);
        A a = ctx.getBean(A.class);
        a.speak();
    }

}
```

Here is my file structure:

[image]

Here is class A, just in case:

```
@Component
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Value("Covid 19")
    private String calamity;

    public void speak() {
        b.writeToScreen(this.calamity);
    }
}
```

Can someone please give me a hint as to what more Springboot wants from me? ;)

P.S.

If I remove the `Bean A` from `Config`, same error persists:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }

}
```

Comment: try without `@Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A();
    }`

Comment: you have already class A and B annotated with @Component. Spring will use classpath scanning to autodetect and configure them. You dont need to define the beans in the configuration class. Try removing it

Comment: @YCF_L didn't work.

Comment: @HenriqueForlani Didn't work

Comment: @JeniaIvanov also check that Helloer is inside your ca.company package, not at the same level. And keep the beans definition removed from the Configuration class. Can you check it?

Comment: Did you set active profile to `client_app_profile_name` in IntelliJ IDEA run configurations window when you run the code? Or you can simply remove the `@Profile()`. And  consider to review your code based on @Henrique Forlani answer below.

Comment: I implemented the recommendations of @HenriqueForlani number 1 and 2, see the screenshot above. I didn't understand number 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem.

1 - Move your Helloer class to inside ca.company package. 
Spring classpath scanning won't work if Helloer is at the same level as ca.company and you will get some error like below:

> This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)

Your structure should be:

```
- java
  - ca.company
    - config
    - hello
      Helloer
```

2 - With spring classpath scan working, you can remove your bean definitions from your Configuration classes, as you will get a double bean definition error.

3 - Remove the annotations you added to suppress the errors in [1].

Comment: Hi Henrique. I moved the main to `ca.company` package as you said in number 1. I removed the bean defnition from `Config` as you said in 2. But what is number 3? Which annotations?

Comment: @JeniaIvanov you excluded the db auto configurations to suppress the errors in [1] I think, right? that is OK, but is not the root cause of your problem. How is it going with the changes I proposed?